# LinkedCaseInsensitive map casting issue with HashMaps with Spring higher version

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, linkedhashmap

The **LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap** is part of the Spring Framework and extends the **LinkedHashMap**

**The hierarchy goes like this:**

java.lang.Object

java.util.AbstractMap

java.util.HashMap

java.util.LinkedHashMap

org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap

For information refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.html

Now I have this code :

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> l_lstResult = (List<HashMap<String, String>>)service.fetchRowwiseMultipleRecords(p_iQueryName, l_hmParams, userDetails);

                l_lstCityTownList = new ArrayList<String>(l_lstResult.size());

                for (int i = 0; i < l_lstResult.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> l_hmColmnData = l_lstResult.get(i);
                    String l_sValue = l_hmColmnData.get(p_sColumnName);
                    l_lstCityTownList.add(l_sValue);
                }
```

The l_lstResult returns a LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap and i get the error in the line  **HashMap l_hmColmnData = l_lstResult.get(i);**

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap cannot be cast to
>   java.util.HashMap

The thing is i get this error with Spring version 4.3.14.RELEASE and no error in 3.2.3.RELEASE. Where is the specification in 3.2.3.RELEASE that allows this casting.

Any suggestions,examples would help me a lot .

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why do you need to cast _l_lstResult_ to a `List<HashMap<String, String>>`? Since  `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap` implements `HashMap`, it provides all it's methods.

Comment: Also, `service.fetchRowwiseMultipleRecords()` returns a **List** of LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap or just a LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap?

Comment: service.fetchRowwiseMultipleRecords() returns list of LinkedCaseInsensitiveMaps.
For the scenario which produced the error it returned a single LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.

The code was like this when i got it

Comment: I want to know how it works in the Spring 3.2.3 version and not in the 4.3.14 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE, LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap doesn't extend anymore LinkedHashMap and HashMap, but only implements Map interface.

[API reference](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.14.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.html).

When you cast `service.fetchRowwiseMultipleRecords(p_iQueryName, l_hmParams, userDetails)` to `List<HashMap<String, String>>` you're just telling the compiler to *trust* you. But then, when it comes to get the first element of the list, it fails because it's **not** a HashMap but a LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap (not extending HashMap).

This will solve your issue

```java
List<LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<String>> l_lstResult = service.fetchRowwiseMultipleRecords(p_iQueryName, l_hmParams, userDetails);

l_lstCityTownList = new ArrayList<String>(l_lstResult.size());

for (int i = 0; i < l_lstResult.size(); i++) {
    LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<String> l_hmColmnData = l_lstResult.get(i);
    String l_sValue = l_hmColmnData.get(p_sColumnName);
    l_lstCityTownList.add(l_sValue);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for . Thanks a lot !