# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap while reading and setting list contents into domain object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, linkedhashmap

I am working in spring batch application. I need to get the list of elements from `ItemWriter` object and set it each list into respective domain object and save it to Mongo DB. But when I am  get trying to get a list from profile object from writer, it has all the data in required list. When I try to assign it to respective domain object, I am getting the error. I am not able to get any data from a list inside the `profileDTO`.

I have tried with multiple ways of getting the list data and set it into respective domain objects. But each time when assigning it to domain class, it through exception that  `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap`

I have also gone through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684878/linkedcaseinsensitive-map-casting-issue-with-hashmaps-with-spring-higher-version?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but i didn't get it.  I am using spring version 5.1.2.
 Please help me to solve this issue.
 below is code snippet

1. `ProfileDTO` which is having List of `DueDiligenceDTO` which is passed into `ItemWriter`. Which hold both profileDTO as well as DueDiligenceDTO data. There is no NullPointers.

   ```
   @Data
   Builder
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @Document(value= "Profile")
   public class ProfileDTO {        
       private long profileId;         
       private LocalDateTime reviewDate;           
       private int tierLevelNumber;  
       private List<DueDiligenceDTO> dueDiligences;            
   }
   ```
2. `DueDiligenceDTO`

   ```
   @Data
   @NoArgsConstructor        
   public class DueDiligenceDto{        
       private String categoryCode;        
   }
   ```

   And the writer class, I have:

   ```
   public class ProfileWriter implements ItemWriter<ProfileDTO> {    
       @Override
       public void write(List<? extends ProfileDTO> profile) throws Exception {        
           riskProfile.stream().forEach(risk -> setProfile(risk));
       }

       private void setProfile(ProfileDTO prop) {
           List<DueDiligence> DueDiligences = new ArrayList<>();

           for(DueDiligenceDTO diligenceDetails :  prop.getDueDiligences()) {
               List<DueDiligenceDetailDTO>  dueDiligenceDtlList= diligenceDetails.getDueDiligenceDetails();
               if(null!=dueDiligenceDtlList && !dueDiligenceDtlList.isEmpty()) {
                   for(DueDiligenceDetailDTO detailDTO:dueDiligenceDtlList) {               
                       // then, need to set detailDTO into separate domain object and
                       // set diligenceDetails into separate domain object.
                    }
                }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   At `for(DueDiligenceDTO diligenceDetails :  prop.getDueDiligences())` -->
   Error stacktrace:
     `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap cannot be cast to com.data.profile.dto.DueDiligenceDetailDTO`

   Please help me how to get it resolved.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post and include the ***complete*** stack trace (format as code).

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you are trying to asign object of `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap` to a variable of `DueDiligenceDetailDTO`

 share the  complete error log and code, so that i can tell you where exactly you need to modify.

Comment: I am trying to get ItemWriter's profileDTO  data which holds a list of DueDiligence and need to set it to separate domian object. so I am using foreach loop to iterate the profileDTO  and set the list of dueDiligence into separate Domain object.